# Is there some way to get certain UIImageView properties?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have just started messing around with xCode, and am trying to give myself a basic introduction to it by tweaking some premade projects.

Currently there is a project that I am working on that has a ball just bouncing around the screen and there is a gameLoop that is setup with the following:

This part is defined in the .m:

```
 - (void)gameLoop {
    if (gameState = kGameStateRunning) {
        ball.center = CGPointMake(ball.center.x + ballVelocity.x, ball.center.y + ballVelocity.y);
        if(ball.center.x > self.view.bounds.size.width || ball.center.x < 0) {
            ballVelocity.x = -ballVelocity.x;
        }

        if(ball.center.y > self.view.bounds.size.height || ball.center.y < 0) {
            ballVelocity.y = -ballVelocity.y;
        }
    }
    else {
        if(tapToBegin.hidden) {
             tapToBegin.hidden = NO;
        }
    }
}
```

What I would like to know, is as opposed to having my UIImageView *ball only bounce off of the walls if it reaches the center, is there a way to make it so that once it hits the edge of ball then it bounces.

First time poster here so I hope I was descriptive enough.

EDIT: I would also like to try doing this so that should I change the radius of the UIImageView without having to adjust constants. Hopefully that is possible, just trying to find out for sheer curiosity. Thanks again guys!

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is to include an offset for the radius of the ball (in pixels), like so:

```
 - (void)gameLoop {
    ball.center = CGPointMake(ball.center.x + ballVelocity.x, ball.center.y + ballVelocity.y);
    int radius = 10; // radius in pixels
    if (gameState = kGameStateRunning) {
        if(ball.center.x + radius > self.view.bounds.size.width || ball.center.x - radius < 0) {
            ballVelocity.x = -ballVelocity.x;
        }
        if(ball.center.y  + radius > self.view.bounds.size.height || ball.center.y - radius < 0) {
            ballVelocity.y = -ballVelocity.y;
        }
    }
    ...
```

There are lots of tutorials on collisions and more advanced physics on pages such as:
[NeHe Productions](http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/lesson.asp?lesson=30)

Hope this helps a bit.

EDIT: In response to your edit about dynamic radius size, try something like (untested):

```
UIImageView *ball;  
CGFloat radius = ball.frame.size.width; // alternatively ball.frame.size.height
```